# Pass field of dynamic object as param

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have dynamic object, that is serialized by NewtonsoftJson

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(settings);
```

I get it from string

`[{"name":"MinDate","value":"01/01/2014"},{"name":"MaxDate","value":"01/31/2014"}]`

I use it in code

```
var minDate = DateTime.MinValue;
var maxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
foreach (var item in data)
{
    switch (item.name)
    {
        case CustomFieldConstants.MinDate:
               DateTime.TryParse(item.value, out minDate);
               break;
        case CustomFieldConstants.MaxDate:
               DateTime.TryParse(item.value, out maxDate);
               break;
    }
}
```

I get compile error

> Error  82  A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

It's not a problem I have to just add cast

```
switch ((string)item.name)
```

Now it compiles. But I get exception, run time error.

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)\' has some invalid arguments

It's not clear for me why it doesn't contain compile errors like with switch when I don't cast it like this

```
DateTime.TryParse((string)item.value, out minDate);
```

?

Notice, `item.value` is type of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `item.value.Value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps also cast the item.value?

```
        var minDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        var maxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            switch (item.name)
            {
                case CustomFieldConstants.MinDate:
                    DateTime.TryParse((string)item.value, out minDate);
                    break;
                case CustomFieldConstants.MaxDate:
                    DateTime.TryParse((string)item.value, out maxDate);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Oh, sorry, I had misread your question initially.

CS1502 is not a runtime error. It is a compile error:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b66k5sz9.aspx

You are not getting an exception (runtime error), but rather a compile error telling you that you are passing wrongly typed arguments.

So it is the same as for the switch, it just is a different error.

Comment: yeah, I know about it, question is not about it, thanks

Comment: ok, I see, thanks, looks like it's specification of switch to accept bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type but not dynamic, but it doesn't check type at compile, as you said early because there is possible any type

Answer (score 1):

I would use it as follows :

```
JArray tokens = JArray.Parse(value);
foreach (JToken token in tokens)
{
    string name = token.Value<string>("name");
    DateTime theDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime.TryParse(token.Value<string>("value"), out theDate);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to get Exception, if there in value incorrect string

Comment: In that case, use TryParse with token.Value<string>("value")